# Can a SocketException end of file be caused by low memory in the server?

Tags: java, spring, sockets

Hi dear community of java addicts.

I was getting these exceptions in a CentOs VM, probably running with low RAM and then I noted that the time was not correctly synchronized between the other VM needed to communicate with my nice component....

I was wondering to know, When ? Why ? How ? A SocketException: end of file is produced in a LINUX server...

These are my logs:

```
    2012-05-16 13:22:41,863 [jmsContainer-1] INFO [ch.swissbytes.cipadapter.services.RuleSetExecutorImpl][initDatabaseProperties] - Initializing database custom properties.
2012-05-16 13:22:41,864 [jmsContainer-1] INFO [ch.swissbytes.cipadapter.services.RuleSetExecutorImpl][initDatabaseProperties] - Setting NLS_DATE_FORMAT to : DD/MM/YYYY HH24:MI:SS
2012-05-16 13:22:47,096 [Timer-2] ERROR [org.jboss.remoting.transport.socket.SocketClientInvoker][handleException] - Got marshalling exception, exiting
java.net.SocketException: end of file
    at org.jboss.remoting.transport.socket.MicroSocketClientInvoker.transport(MicroSocketClientInvoker.java:685)
    at org.jboss.remoting.transport.bisocket.BisocketClientInvoker.transport(BisocketClientInvoker.java:458)
    at org.jboss.remoting.MicroRemoteClientInvoker.invoke(MicroRemoteClientInvoker.java:141)
    at org.jboss.remoting.ConnectionValidator.doCheckConnectionWithoutLease(ConnectionValidator.java:828)
    at org.jboss.remoting.ConnectionValidator.run(ConnectionValidator.java:345)
    at java.util.TimerThread.mainLoop(Timer.java:512)
    at java.util.TimerThread.run(Timer.java:462)
2012-05-16 13:22:47,288 [Thread-2624] WARN [org.jboss.remoting.Client][removeListener] - unable to remove remote callback handler: Can not get connection to server. Problem establishing socket connection for InvokerLocator [bisocket://ams-dev-bo.swissbytes.ch:4457//?JBM_clientMaxPoolSize=200&clientLeasePeriod=10000&clientSocketClass=org.jboss.jms.client.remoting.ClientSocketWrapper&dataType=jms&failureDisconnectTimeout=0&marshaller=org.jboss.jms.wireformat.JMSWireFormat&socket.check_connection=false&stopLeaseOnFailure=true&timeout=0&unmarshaller=org.jboss.jms.wireformat.JMSWireFormat&useClientConnectionIdentity=true&validatorPingPeriod=10000&validatorPingTimeout=5000]
2012-05-16 13:22:47,329 [Thread-2625] WARN [org.jboss.remoting.Client][removeListener] - unable to remove remote callback handler: Can not get connection to server. Problem establishing socket connection for InvokerLocator [bisocket://ams-dev-bo.swissbytes.ch:4457//?JBM_clientMaxPoolSize=200&clientLeasePeriod=10000&clientSocketClass=org.jboss.jms.client.remoting.ClientSocketWrapper&dataType=jms&failureDisconnectTimeout=0&marshaller=org.jboss.jms.wireformat.JMSWireFormat&socket.check_connection=false&stopLeaseOnFailure=true&timeout=0&unmarshaller=org.jboss.jms.wireformat.JMSWireFormat&useClientConnectionIdentity=true&validatorPingPeriod=10000&validatorPingTimeout=5000]
2012-05-16 13:22:51,146 [Timer-4] WARN [org.jboss.remoting.transport.bisocket.BisocketServerInvoker][run] - org.jboss.remoting.transport.bisocket.BisocketServerInvoker$ControlMonitorTimerTask@7a7385ac: detected failure on control connection Thread[control: Socket[addr=ams-dev-bo.swissbytes.ch/192.168.0.190,port=11641,localport=57623],5,] (5c4o020-jlorp4-h29d35xs-1-h2aawvkq-l2t: requesting new control connection
2012-05-16 13:22:51,159 [controlConnectionRecreate:control: Socket[addr=ams-dev-bo.swissbytes.ch/192.168.0.190,port=11641,localport=57623]] ERROR [org.jboss.remoting.transport.bisocket.BisocketServerInvoker][createControlConnection] - unable to get secondary locator
org.jboss.remoting.CannotConnectException: Can not get connection to server. Problem establishing socket connection for InvokerLocator [bisocket://ams-dev-bo.swissbytes.ch:4457//?JBM_clientMaxPoolSize=200&clientLeasePeriod=10000&clientSocketClass=org.jboss.jms.client.remoting.ClientSocketWrapper&dataType=jms&failureDisconnectTimeout=0&marshaller=org.jboss.jms.wireformat.JMSWireFormat&socket.check_connection=false&stopLeaseOnFailure=true&timeout=0&unmarshaller=org.jboss.jms.wireformat.JMSWireFormat&useClientConnectionIdentity=true&validatorPingPeriod=10000&validatorPingTimeout=5000]
    at org.jboss.remoting.transport.socket.MicroSocketClientInvoker.transport(MicroSocketClientInvoker.java:613)
    at org.jboss.remoting.transport.bisocket.BisocketClientInvoker.transport(BisocketClientInvoker.java:458)
    at org.jboss.remoting.MicroRemoteClientInvoker.invoke(MicroRemoteClientInvoker.java:141)
    at org.jboss.remoting.transport.bisocket.BisocketClientInvoker.getSecondaryLocator(BisocketClientInvoker.java:640)
    at org.jboss.remoting.transport.bisocket.BisocketServerInvoker.createControlConnection(BisocketServerInvoker.java:230)
    at org.jboss.remoting.transport.bisocket.BisocketServerInvoker$ControlMonitorTimerTask$1.run(BisocketServerInvoker.java:1048)
Caused by: java.net.ConnectException: Connection refused
    at java.net.PlainSocketImpl.socketConnect(Native Method)
    at java.net.PlainSocketImpl.doConnect(PlainSocketImpl.java:351)
    at java.net.PlainSocketImpl.connectToAddress(PlainSocketImpl.java:213)
    at java.net.PlainSocketImpl.connect(PlainSocketImpl.java:200)
    at java.net.SocksSocketImpl.connect(SocksSocketImpl.java:366)
    at java.net.Socket.connect(Socket.java:529)
    at org.jboss.remoting.transport.socket.SocketClientInvoker.createSocket(SocketClientInvoker.java:192)
    at org.jboss.remoting.transport.bisocket.BisocketClientInvoker.createSocket(BisocketClientInvoker.java:465)
    at org.jboss.remoting.transport.socket.MicroSocketClientInvoker.getConnection(MicroSocketClientInvoker.java:913)
    at org.jboss.remoting.transport.socket.MicroSocketClientInvoker.transport(MicroSocketClientInvoker.java:602)
    ... 5 more
2012-05-16 13:22:51,161 [controlConnectionRecreate:control: Socket[addr=ams-dev-bo.swissbytes.ch/192.168.0.190,port=11641,localport=57623]] ERROR [org.jboss.remoting.transport.bisocket.BisocketServerInvoker][run] - Unable to recreate control connection: InvokerLocator [null://ams-dev-bo.swissbytes.ch:11641/null]
java.io.IOException: unable to get secondary locator: Can not get connection to server. Problem establishing socket connection for InvokerLocator [bisocket://ams-dev-bo.swissbytes.ch:4457//?JBM_clientMaxPoolSize=200&clientLeasePeriod=10000&clientSocketClass=org.jboss.jms.client.remoting.ClientSocketWrapper&dataType=jms&failureDisconnectTimeout=0&marshaller=org.jboss.jms.wireformat.JMSWireFormat&socket.check_connection=false&stopLeaseOnFailure=true&timeout=0&unmarshaller=org.jboss.jms.wireformat.JMSWireFormat&useClientConnectionIdentity=true&validatorPingPeriod=10000&validatorPingTimeout=5000]
    at org.jboss.remoting.transport.bisocket.BisocketServerInvoker.createControlConnection(BisocketServerInvoker.java:235)
    at org.jboss.remoting.transport.bisocket.BisocketServerInvoker$ControlMonitorTimerTask$1.run(BisocketServerInvoker.java:1048)
2012-05-16 13:22:56,870 [jmsContainer-1] INFO [ch.swissbytes.cipadapter.services.RuleSetExecutorImpl][runFilterRec] - Query for the level[1] was executed.
2012-05-16 13:22:56,871 [jmsContainer-1] INFO [ch.swissbytes.cipadapter.services.RuleSetExecutorImpl][doFilterResultsCotainCipAdress] - doFilterResultsCotainCipAdress() - Searching Cip Address: 1213194
2012-05-16 13:22:56,871 [jmsContainer-1] INFO [ch.swissbytes.cipadapter.services.RuleSetExecutorImpl][runFilterRec] - cipAddress: 1213194 was NOT FOUND in Filter Results
2012-05-16 13:22:56,871 [jmsContainer-1] INFO [ch.swissbytes.cipadapter.services.RuleSetExecutorImpl][runFilterRec] - Current result size is not on filter's range : filter1 => [ 1 , 10 ] vs 0
2012-05-16 13:22:56,871 [jmsContainer-1] INFO [ch.swissbytes.cipadapter.jms.request.SimilarDebtorsProcessor][delegateFixedResult] - Fixed result GET_SIMILAR_DEBTORS  totalSize: 1 -> fixedSize: 1
2012-05-16 13:22:56,872 [jmsContainer-1] INFO [ch.swissbytes.cipadapter.util.ListFragmenter][fragmentList] - Preparing [0] fragments in chunks of size [500]
2012-05-16 13:22:56,872 [jmsContainer-1] INFO [ch.swissbytes.cipadapter.util.ListFragmenter][fragmentList] - List fragment range[0-1]
2012-05-16 13:22:56,872 [jmsContainer-1] INFO [ch.swissbytes.cipadapter.jms.request.SimilarDebtorsProcessor][processFragment] - Sending 'SimilarDebtors' message fragment[0-1]
2012-05-16 13:22:56,980 [jmsContainer-1] ERROR [ch.swissbytes.cipadapter.jms.request.CipAdapterBean][onMessage] - JMSException caused by Message[ID:JBM-5a9ac639-f2a4-436c-8170-37378d8b606b], somenthing is wrong with the communication.
2012-05-16 13:22:56,982 [jmsContainer-1] INFO [ch.swissbytes.cipadapter.jms.request.CipAdapterBean][onMessage] - Queue listener will be stopped.
2012-05-16 13:22:56,983 [jmsContainer-1] INFO [ch.swissbytes.cipadapter.jms.request.CipAdapterBean][stopListener] - Listener successfully stopped
2012-05-16 13:22:56,984 [jmsContainer-1] DEBUG [ch.swissbytes.cipadapter.jms.request.CipAdapterBean][errorTemplateSend] - Trying to send error message to AMS-WA error queue.
2012-05-16 13:22:56,985 [jmsContainer-1] DEBUG [ch.swissbytes.cipadapter.jms.request.CipAdapterBean][errorTemplateSend] - Adapter id: 1
2012-05-16 13:22:57,014 [jmsContainer-1] ERROR [org.jboss.jms.client.container.ClosedInterceptor][invoke] - ClosedInterceptor.ClientSessionDelegate[ioy8-vyl6fa2h-1-hbl1g92h-qrmrca-a50o4c5]: method getTransacted() did not go through, the interceptor is CLOSED
2012-05-16 13:22:57,016 [jmsContainer-1] ERROR [org.springframework.jms.listener.DefaultMessageListenerContainer][rollbackOnExceptionIfNecessary] - Application exception overridden by rollback exception
org.springframework.jms.UncategorizedJmsException: Uncategorized exception occured during JMS processing; nested exception is org.jboss.jms.exception.MessagingNetworkFailureException; nested exception is org.jboss.remoting.CannotConnectException: Error setting up client lease upon performing connect.
    at org.springframework.jms.support.JmsUtils.convertJmsAccessException(JmsUtils.java:292)
    at org.springframework.jms.support.JmsAccessor.convertJmsAccessException(JmsAccessor.java:168)
    at org.springframework.jms.core.JmsTemplate.execute(JmsTemplate.java:474)
    at org.springframework.jms.core.JmsTemplate.send(JmsTemplate.java:548)
    at org.springframework.jms.core.JmsTemplate.send(JmsTemplate.java:534)
    at ch.swissbytes.cipadapter.jms.request.CipAdapterBean.errorTemplateSend(CipAdapterBean.java:226)
    at ch.swissbytes.cipadapter.jms.request.CipAdapterBean.onMessage(CipAdapterBean.java:160)
    at org.springframework.jms.listener.AbstractMessageListenerContainer.doInvokeListener(AbstractMessageListenerContainer.java:506)
    at org.springframework.jms.listener.AbstractMessageListenerContainer.invokeListener(AbstractMessageListenerContainer.java:463)
    at org.springframework.jms.listener.AbstractMessageListenerContainer.doExecuteListener(AbstractMessageListenerContainer.java:435)
    at org.springframework.jms.listener.AbstractPollingMessageListenerContainer.doReceiveAndExecute(AbstractPollingMessageListenerContainer.java:322)
    at org.springframework.jms.listener.AbstractPollingMessageListenerContainer.receiveAndExecute(AbstractPollingMessageListenerContainer.java:240)
    at org.springframework.jms.listener.DefaultMessageListenerContainer$AsyncMessageListenerInvoker.invokeListener(DefaultMessageListenerContainer.java:944)
    at org.springframework.jms.listener.DefaultMessageListenerContainer$AsyncMessageListenerInvoker.run(DefaultMessageListenerContainer.java:868)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:662)
Caused by: org.jboss.jms.exception.MessagingNetworkFailureException
    at org.jboss.jms.client.delegate.DelegateSupport.handleThrowable(DelegateSupport.java:240)
    at org.jboss.jms.client.delegate.ClientConnectionFactoryDelegate.org$jboss$jms$client$delegate$ClientConnectionFactoryDelegate$createConnectionDelegate$aop(ClientConnectionFactoryDelegate.java:198)
    at org.jboss.jms.client.delegate.ClientConnectionFactoryDelegate$createConnectionDelegate_N3019492359065420858.invokeNext(ClientConnectionFactoryDelegate$createConnectionDelegate_N3019492359065420858.java)
    at org.jboss.jms.client.container.StateCreationAspect.handleCreateConnectionDelegate(StateCreationAspect.java:80)
    at org.jboss.aop.advice.org.jboss.jms.client.container.StateCreationAspect0.invoke(StateCreationAspect0.java)
    at org.jboss.jms.client.delegate.ClientConnectionFactoryDelegate$createConnectionDelegate_N3019492359065420858.invokeNext(ClientConnectionFactoryDelegate$createConnectionDelegate_N3019492359065420858.java)
    at org.jboss.jms.client.delegate.ClientConnectionFactoryDelegate.createConnectionDelegate(ClientConnectionFactoryDelegate.java)
    at org.jboss.jms.client.JBossConnectionFactory.createConnectionInternal(JBossConnectionFactory.java:205)
    at org.jboss.jms.client.JBossConnectionFactory.createConnection(JBossConnectionFactory.java:87)
    at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor18.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:25)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:597)
    at org.springframework.aop.support.AopUtils.invokeJoinpointUsingReflection(AopUtils.java:310)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.JdkDynamicAopProxy.invoke(JdkDynamicAopProxy.java:198)
    at $Proxy0.createConnection(Unknown Source)
    at org.springframework.jms.connection.UserCredentialsConnectionFactoryAdapter.doCreateConnection(UserCredentialsConnectionFactoryAdapter.java:174)
    at org.springframework.jms.connection.UserCredentialsConnectionFactoryAdapter.createConnection(UserCredentialsConnectionFactoryAdapter.java:149)
    at org.springframework.jms.connection.SingleConnectionFactory.doCreateConnection(SingleConnectionFactory.java:316)
    at org.springframework.jms.connection.SingleConnectionFactory.initConnection(SingleConnectionFactory.java:270)
    at org.springframework.jms.connection.SingleConnectionFactory.createConnection(SingleConnectionFactory.java:215)
    at org.springframework.jms.support.JmsAccessor.createConnection(JmsAccessor.java:184)
    at org.springframework.jms.core.JmsTemplate.execute(JmsTemplate.java:461)
    ... 12 more
Caused by: org.jboss.remoting.CannotConnectException: Error setting up client lease upon performing connect.
    at org.jboss.remoting.Client.connect(Client.java:1804)
    at org.jboss.remoting.Client.connect(Client.java:652)
    at org.jboss.jms.client.remoting.JMSRemotingConnection$1.run(JMSRemotingConnection.java:374)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at org.jboss.jms.client.remoting.JMSRemotingConnection.start(JMSRemotingConnection.java:368)
    at org.jboss.jms.client.delegate.ClientConnectionFactoryDelegate.org$jboss$jms$client$delegate$ClientConnectionFactoryDelegate$createConnectionDelegate$aop(ClientConnectionFactoryDelegate.java:165)
    ... 32 more
Caused by: java.lang.Exception: Error setting up client lease
    at org.jboss.remoting.MicroRemoteClientInvoker.establishLease(MicroRemoteClientInvoker.java:508)
    at org.jboss.remoting.Client.setupClientLease(Client.java:1912)
    at org.jboss.remoting.Client.connect(Client.java:1800)
    ... 37 more
Caused by: org.jboss.remoting.CannotConnectException: Can not get connection to server. Problem establishing socket connection for InvokerLocator [bisocket://ams-dev-bo.swissbytes.ch:4457//?JBM_clientMaxPoolSize=200&clientLeasePeriod=10000&clientSocketClass=org.jboss.jms.client.remoting.ClientSocketWrapper&dataType=jms&failureDisconnectTimeout=0&marshaller=org.jboss.jms.wireformat.JMSWireFormat&socket.check_connection=false&stopLeaseOnFailure=true&timeout=0&unmarshaller=org.jboss.jms.wireformat.JMSWireFormat&useClientConnectionIdentity=true&validatorPingPeriod=10000&validatorPingTimeout=5000]
    at org.jboss.remoting.transport.socket.MicroSocketClientInvoker.transport(MicroSocketClientInvoker.java:613)
    at org.jboss.remoting.transport.bisocket.BisocketClientInvoker.transport(BisocketClientInvoker.java:458)
    at org.jboss.remoting.MicroRemoteClientInvoker.invoke(MicroRemoteClientInvoker.java:141)
    at org.jboss.remoting.MicroRemoteClientInvoker.establishLease(MicroRemoteClientInvoker.java:474)
    ... 39 more
Caused by: java.net.ConnectException: Connection refused
    at java.net.PlainSocketImpl.socketConnect(Native Method)
    at java.net.PlainSocketImpl.doConnect(PlainSocketImpl.java:351)
    at java.net.PlainSocketImpl.connectToAddress(PlainSocketImpl.java:213)
    at java.net.PlainSocketImpl.connect(PlainSocketImpl.java:200)
    at java.net.SocksSocketImpl.connect(SocksSocketImpl.java:366)
    at java.net.Socket.connect(Socket.java:529)
    at org.jboss.remoting.transport.socket.SocketClientInvoker.createSocket(SocketClientInvoker.java:192)
    at org.jboss.remoting.transport.bisocket.BisocketClientInvoker.createSocket(BisocketClientInvoker.java:465)
    at org.jboss.remoting.transport.socket.MicroSocketClientInvoker.getConnection(MicroSocketClientInvoker.java:913)
    at org.jboss.remoting.transport.socket.MicroSocketClientInvoker.transport(MicroSocketClientInvoker.java:602)
    ... 42 more
2012-05-16 13:22:57,031 [jmsContainer-1] WARN [org.springframework.jms.listener.DefaultMessageListenerContainer][handleListenerException] - Execution of JMS message listener failed
javax.jms.IllegalStateException: The object is closed
    at org.jboss.jms.client.container.ClosedInterceptor.invoke(ClosedInterceptor.java:157)
    at org.jboss.aop.advice.PerInstanceInterceptor.invoke(PerInstanceInterceptor.java:105)
    at org.jboss.jms.client.delegate.ClientSessionDelegate$getTransacted_N1613179584734032131.invokeNext(ClientSessionDelegate$getTransacted_N1613179584734032131.java)
    at org.jboss.jms.client.delegate.ClientSessionDelegate.getTransacted(ClientSessionDelegate.java)
    at org.jboss.jms.client.JBossSession.getTransacted(JBossSession.java:154)
    at org.springframework.jms.listener.AbstractMessageListenerContainer.rollbackOnExceptionIfNecessary(AbstractMessageListenerContainer.java:574)
    at org.springframework.jms.listener.AbstractMessageListenerContainer.doExecuteListener(AbstractMessageListenerContainer.java:442)
    at org.springframework.jms.listener.AbstractPollingMessageListenerContainer.doReceiveAndExecute(AbstractPollingMessageListenerContainer.java:322)
    at org.springframework.jms.listener.AbstractPollingMessageListenerContainer.receiveAndExecute(AbstractPollingMessageListenerContainer.java:240)
    at org.springframework.jms.listener.DefaultMessageListenerContainer$AsyncMessageListenerInvoker.invokeListener(DefaultMessageListenerContainer.java:944)
    at org.springframework.jms.listener.DefaultMessageListenerContainer$AsyncMessageListenerInvoker.run(DefaultMessageListenerContainer.java:868)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:662)
2012-05-16 13:22:57,072 [jmsContainer-1] WARN [org.jboss.remoting.Client][removeListener] - unable to remove remote callback handler: Can not get connection to server. Problem establishing socket connection for InvokerLocator [bisocket://ams-dev-bo.swissbytes.ch:4457//?JBM_clientMaxPoolSize=200&clientLeasePeriod=10000&clientSocketClass=org.jboss.jms.client.remoting.ClientSocketWrapper&dataType=jms&failureDisconnectTimeout=0&marshaller=org.jboss.jms.wireformat.JMSWireFormat&socket.check_connection=false&stopLeaseOnFailure=true&timeout=0&unmarshaller=org.jboss.jms.wireformat.JMSWireFormat&useClientConnectionIdentity=true&validatorPingPeriod=10000&validatorPingTimeout=5000]
2012-05-16 13:23:35,981 [org.springframework.scheduling.timer.TimerFactoryBean#0] DEBUG [ch.swissbytes.cipadapter.services.tasks.CheckQueueListenerStatus][run] - Checking queueListener status
```

And error was originated in this method:

```
private void initDatabaseProperties(final Session session) {
    logger.info("Initializing database custom properties.");
    properties.getProperty(CommonConstants.CIP_DATE_FORMAT_PROP);
    final String dateFormat = DateUtil.VIEW_DATE_FORMAT;
    logger.info("Setting NLS_DATE_FORMAT to : " + dateFormat);
    final String queryString = "ALTER SESSION SET NLS_DATE_FORMAT = '" +      StringUtils.trim(dateFormat) + "'";
    session.createSQLQuery(queryString).executeUpdate();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I can't answer for what exceptions JBoss throws, but in general EOS on a socket is caused by exactly one thing: receiving a FIN from the peer as the result of a close or shutdown output by the peer.

Comment: Thanks EJP, I'cant do anything if this happens from the peer side. Just capture the exception and handle it.